# How do I remove duplicate entries in this T-SQL query containing LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, group-by, left-join

I am having issues taking out duplicate entries from this query containing multiple LEFT OUTER JOINs

```
SELECT s.Category,
       SUM(spons.SPONS) AS SPONSOREDAMT,
       SUM(priv.PRIV)   AS PRIVATEAMT FROM   (SELECT ID   AS ID,
               Name AS Category FROM   dbo.ServicesTable) s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ( ServiceId )   AS ServiceId,
                                        DateCreated,
                                        SUM(SPONSORAMT) AS SPONS
                        FROM   dbo.SponsorMonthlyBill
                        GROUP  BY ServiceId,
                                  DateCreated) spons
         ON ( s.ID = spons.ServiceId )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ( ServiceId )   AS ServiceId,
                                        DateCreated,
                                        SUM(PRIVATEAMT) AS PRIV
                        FROM   dbo.PrivateMonthlyBill
                        GROUP  BY ServiceId,
                                  DateCreated) priv
         ON ( s.ID = priv.ServiceId )
            AND ( MONTH(priv.DateCreated) = MONTH('2011-08-04') )
GROUP  BY s.Category,
          spons.SPONS,
          priv.PRIV
```

If I make last line look like this:

```
GROUP BY s.Category
```

instead of what its now, I'll have the duplicate entries adding up. If there are more than double entries, all 3 or 4 or more get added up. So how go about this.

Scorpi0 gave an answer which worked but needs some extra modification. This was the modification I made to it:

```
SELECT  s.Name AS Category,
   SUM(spons.SPONS) AS SPONSOREDAMT,
   SUM(priv.PRIV) AS PRIVATEAMT, SUM(spons.SPONS) + SUM(priv.PRIV) as 
   TOTAL,spons.DateCreated

   FROM   dbo.ServicesTable s
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ServiceId,DateCreated,
                           SUM(SPONSORAMT) AS SPONS
                    FROM   dbo.SponsorMonthlyBill
                    GROUP  BY ServiceId,DateCreated) spons
     ON ( s.ID = spons.ServiceId )
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT distinct ServiceId,
                           SUM(PRIVATEAMT) AS PRIV
                    FROM   dbo.PrivateMonthlyBill
                    GROUP  BY ServiceId
                    ) priv
     ON ( s.ID = priv.ServiceId )
GROUP  BY s.Name,spons.DateCreated
```

I know it introduced the duplicates again but how can keep the `DateCreated` out of GROUP BY and still access it in the main SELECT clause? Please keep in mind that this is a View and there are some rules that it insists must be followed.

Comment: Judging by your code, you seem to be thinking that DISTINCT is applied to a single column. That is not so. In SQL Server, DISTINCT is always applied to all the columns being pulled.

Comment: You are grouping by `ServiceId` and `DateCreated` in both subselects, but only the second one seems to be needing that, because of the `MONTH(priv.DateCreated) = MONTH('2011-08-04')` condition in the `ON` clause. Is that really so or you just forgot to add a similar condition to the first LEFT JOIN? Also, what is it actually you are intending to filter out with that condition? Do you mean to filter out *rows* that have `DateCreated` in August? Or should that be *groups* of same `ServiceId` rows that have at least one `DateCreated` in August?

Comment: I need to be able to see only transactions done in August. Actually, I need this query is inside a view and the view would be the basis of a report. To achieve this, i need to make DateCreated part of the select clause at the top and part of one of the select clauses in the subqueries. This will now leave me with the following    modified code...Please look at the comment below the Answer because the remaining characters will not be enough

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicates are coming from your useless group by DateCreated.

Try with this query, it should give you the right results:

```
SELECT s.Name AS Category,
       SUM(spons.SPONS) AS SPONSOREDAMT,
       SUM(priv.PRIV)   AS PRIVATEAMT
FROM   dbo.ServicesTable s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ServiceId,
                               SUM(SPONSORAMT) AS SPONS
                        FROM   dbo.SponsorMonthlyBill
                        GROUP  BY ServiceId) spons
         ON ( s.ID = spons.ServiceId )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ServiceId
                               SUM(PRIVATEAMT) AS PRIV
                        FROM   dbo.PrivateMonthlyBill
                        WHERE MONTH(DateCreated) = MONTH('2011-08-04')
                        GROUP  BY ServiceId
                        ) priv
         ON ( s.ID = priv.ServiceId )
GROUP  BY s.Name
```

Comment: Neither `spons` nor `priv` contain a `ServiceId` column. You are grouping by it, yes, but you are not selecting it. Just forgot?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Scorpi0. However, the reason i put the group by DateCreated is because it required me to do so if i wanted to expose DateCreated as a property of spons or priv and use it in the main SELECT clause as one of the fields to be displayed. Besides, this query is inside a view and needs the datecreated field for us to parameterize the view by datecreated in a Report. Any help with that?

Comment: Well, post your complete query so! The original query doesn't output dateCreated, so you doesn't need it. If in fact you need it, it is a whole new problem: do you need to sum by date created? Is the date created only used to filter on the month of PrivateMonthlyBill? etc...

Comment: Can I parameterize a View? I know you can do that with a report but a view in SQL Server is it possible? Another thing I can do is to include a datecreated in the main SELECT clause, sub query select clause and in the main GROUP BY clause and sub query GROUP BY clause and then it can be parameterized in a report as i specified in my modified question. Please which way do I go.

Comment: You cannot parametrise a view but you might consider a (table-valued) function, which you *can* parametrise. As for the `DateCreated` column, it is not quite clear what values should that column contain. My understanding is, `DateCreated` holds creation dates pertaining to particular bills. Now, the result set of your query is supposed to contain aggregated sums, i.e. one such sum "consists" of many bills. So, which one of them should `DateCreated` represent alongside the sum? I mean, `DateCreated` should be aggregated too, but the question is, in what way? `MIN`? `MAX`? Something else?

Comment: Actually, the date should not be aggregated. The datecreated is actually needed to specify the month for the query.Therefore it will apply to both dbo.SponsorMonthlyBill and dbo.PrivateMonthlyBill entities. So the best option would be to use (table-value)function with an integer parameter for the month. However I want to explore the View Option totally. It looks like I'm almost done exploring that.